# container.ListBlobs is giving a list of CloudBlobDirectory I was expecting a list of CloudBlockBlobs?

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I am using container.ListBlobs, but it seems to be returning a list {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.LazyEnumerable} however when I do a foreach the object seems to be CloudBlobDirectory  instead of a list of CloudBlockBlobs. Am I doing something wrong, or is this what it should return?  Is there some way I can just get a list of the blobs, rather than blobdirectories?

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(conn);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blobs = container.ListBlobs();
foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
   Console.WriteLine(blob.GetType().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what your file structure looks like? If you have directories with Blobs inside your container, they would show directories.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee772878(v=azure.95).aspx) for `CloudBloblContainer.ListBlobs()`:

> The types of objects returned by the ListBlobs method depend on the
>   type of listing that is being performed. If the UseFlatBlobListing
>   property is set to true, the listing will return an enumerable
>   collection of CloudBlob objects. If UseFlatBlobListing is set to false
>   (the default value), the listing may return a collection containing
>   CloudBlob objects and CloudBlobDirectory objects. The latter case
>   provides a convenience for subsequent enumerations over a virtual blob
>   hierarchy.

So, if you only want blobs, you have to set the `UseFlatBlobListing` property option to true.

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(conn);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
// ** new code below ** //
BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions();
options.UseFlatBlobListing = true;
// ** new code above ** //
var blobs = container.ListBlobs(options); // <-- add the parameter to overload
foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(blob.GetType().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Bob I wasn't able to do exactly as you said (options.UseFlatBlobListing = true;) was not coming up but I did this: var blobs = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);

Comment: With latest Azure SDK, container.ListBlobs(prefix: "as needed", useFlatBlobListing: true) works.
+1 @DermFrench